# What would be the proper interpretation for this Quote by Dennis Prager?

Tags: meaning, interpretation

> Rather than dividing the world between good and evil, the Left divided the world in terms of economics. Economic classes, not moral values, explained human behavior. Therefore, to cite a common example, poverty, not one's moral value system, or lack of it, caused crime.

{poverty, not one's moral value system, or lack of it, caused crime.}

I don't understand properly this sentence. but what I infer is:
it doesn't matter if one person has moral values rather than if he is poor, because poverty causes crime.
Is it right my inference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shortest answer: crime is the inherent result of poverty and not bad morals.

A longer answer: They mean that the environment or system that those who are committing crime are not bad people or have bad more morals, but instead that their circumstances or being poor has forced them into a situation where they had to commit crimes to survive.

Comment: Thanks For the answer!! Regards!